# React + Redux Noob - Submitting Form Data

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux

I've just started trying out react after a few tutorials on Redux and React and I'm getting an error in the console:

> Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs (See ref
>   "username" in FieldGroup created by Login). Attempts to access this
>   ref will fail.

What is the proper way to pass form field input values to my submit button? Should these values go into the redux store? After reading the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#a-complete-example it seems like I should avoid refs in this case. So, without refs how do I get the input values to the submit button? Thanks for any help.

***Login.jsx***

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Row, Col, FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, HelpBlock, Checkbox, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Login extends Component {

  render() {
    const { errorMessage } = this.props;
    function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
      return (
        <FormGroup controlId={id}>
          <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl {...props} />
          {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
        </FormGroup>
      );
    }

    const formInstance = (


          <Col xs={12} md={8} mdOffset={2}>
            <code>&lt;{'Col xs={12} md={8}'} /&gt;</code>
            <form>
              <FieldGroup
                id="formControlsEmail"
                type="email"
                label="Email address"
                placeholder="Enter email"
                ref="username"
              />
              <FieldGroup
                id="formControlsPassword"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                ref="password"
              />
              <Checkbox checked readOnly>
                Checkbox
              </Checkbox>

              <Button type="submit" onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}>
                Submit
              </Button>
              {errorMessage &&
                <p>{errorMessage}</p>
              }
            </form>
          </Col>

    );
    return formInstance;
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const username = this.refs.username
    const password = this.refs.password
    const creds = { username: username.value.trim(), password: password.value.trim() }
    this.props.onLoginClick(creds)
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  onLoginClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  errorMessage: PropTypes.string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional components in react (stateless) don't have **refs**.

From the official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-functional-components)

> Refs and Functional Components
>   You may not use the ref attribute on functional components because they don’t have instances:

Use an ES6 class instead if you need refs, if not use `this.state` from your Parent `Login` component with class syntax and use that instead with `this.setState(yourState)` when the input value changes on your `FieldGroup`

And then in your you would do

```
handleClick(event) {
    const username = this.state.username
    const password = this.state.password
    const creds = { username: username.value.trim(), password: password.value.trim() }
    this.props.onLoginClick(creds)
  }
```

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-functional-components) :

> You can, however, use the ref attribute inside a functional component as long as you refer to a DOM element or a class component: